# How can I set leaftlet CircleMarker radius in feet?

Tags: styles, leaflet, geojson, marker

I'm trying to built a layer made out of CircleMarkers on LeafLet, but I'm having an hard time trying to give the Radius property a proper meaning since it's supposedly expressed in pixels.

I need to construct circle markers that have a radius of 500feet, so how can I represents that since the CircleMarker property is in pixels?

Thank you!

```
GeoJsonStyle nodeFenceStyle = new GeoJsonStyle();
nodeFenceStyle.weight = 2;
nodeFenceStyle.radius = *500feet*;
//nodeFenceStyle.opacity = 0.65
nodeFenceStyle.color = "#FFA500"; 
nodeFenceStyle.fillColor = nodeFenceStyle.color;
nodeFenceStyle.fillOpacity = 0.65;
```

Comment: Have you considered using the [Circle class](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#circle)? You can specify the radius in meters. 500 feet is 152.4 meters. So `L.circle([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 152.4}).addTo(map);` would create a circle that has a radius of 500 feet at that position.

Comment: @Iavor you should turn your comment into a proper answer.

Comment: @gabe91 CircleMarker sounds not appropriate to your case. It will be resized on every zoom. That is why its size is specified in pixels. On the contrary, Circle will scale with map zoom, like a map feature. That is why its size in specified in meters, as pointed out by Iavor.

Comment: @ghybs I guess I didn't answer properly because I wasn't sure if gabe91 needed a specific functionality that only the CircleMarker class had. But looking at the [docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#circle) again, I see that Circle 'extends CircleMarker' so it has all the functionality of CircleMarker (plus the added benefit of creating circles with a radius that is specified in meters :) ).

Comment: @lavor yours was the exact answer I was looking for, thank you! :)

Comment: @ghybs thanks for the explanation! Basically CircleMarker always keeps the same number of pixels no matter how much you zoom and that's why it was in pixels. thanks!